# AWS Lambda timeout issue with spring boot application

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timeout

I have a spring boot application which I am trying to deploy on AWS lambda .

I added StreamLambdaHandler as the handler class

public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

```
private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;

static {
    try {
        //handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(SituationalFlexibilityApp.class);

        // For applications that take longer than 10 seconds to start, use the async builder:

         handler = new SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder<AwsProxyRequest>()
                            .defaultProxy()
                            .asyncInit()
                            .springBootApplication(SituationalFlexibilityApp.class)
                            .buildAndInitialize();

        // we use the onStartup method of the handler to register our custom filter
        handler.onStartup(servletContext -> {
            FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addFilter("CognitoIdentityFilter",CognitoIdentityFilter.class);
            registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "/*");
        });
    } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
        // if we fail here. We re-throw the exception to force another cold start
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
    }
}

public StreamLambdaHandler() {
    Timer.enable();
}
 

/*
 * public StreamLambdaHandler() throws ContainerInitializationException {
 * 
 * handler = new SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder() .defaultProxy() .asyncInit()
 * .springBootApplication(SlowApplication.class) .buildAndInitialize(); }
 */

@Override
public void handleRequest(InputStream input, OutputStream output, Context context) throws IOException {
    handler.proxyStream(input, output, context);

}
```

When I test it on AWS lambda I get below exception
com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.ContainerInitializationException: Could not initialize framework within the 20000ms timeout

so I updated the lambda configuration for a timeout of 5 mins and added below line in the static block of the StreamLambdaHandler class
LambdaContainerHandler.getContainerConfig().setInitializationTimeout(2000000);

Now, I am seeing below exception
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find timer SPRINGBOOT2_COLD_START

Can someone please point me in the correct direction as I a noob in AWS services and lambda

Comment: is this issue resolved? I am seeing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing this error after commenting out the below code in *StreamLambdaHandler* method

```
// Timer.enable();
```